# How to get top parent Category from current category object?

Tags: category, magento-1

How can I get the top level parent category (just after Default Category) from current category object? I want the Category Name and Category URL of that parent category to show in the subcategories.

- Default Category

  - Cat A

    - Cat B

      - Cat C

How can I get `Cat A`'s Name and URL in `Cat B` and `Cat C` objects?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`$category->getPath()` will return the ids of all categories from the tree root to the current one separated by slash (`/`). Here is an example: `1/2/56/124/543`.
The first one is the 'root of roots'. The second one is the catalog root (default category). The rest of them are simple categories.
So you can do something like this.

```
$path = $category->getPath();
$ids = explode('/', $path);
if (isset($ids[2])){
    $topParent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($ids[2]);
}
else{
    $topParent = null;//it means you are in one catalog root.
}
```

Now you can get the name and url like this:

```
if ($topParent){
    $name = $topParent->getName();
    $url = $topParent->getUrl();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius! There was a typo in `getId()` I corrected it. It's working perfectly.

Comment: cool. sorry about the typo. and thanks for the correction.

Comment: Hi, can anyone refer me to the official magento document for the category tree?

Comment: @Marius when I get path of category all of category says 1/2/<Respective Category ID> My default category id is 2. Then what is this 1?

Comment: @invissible 1 is the "root of all roots". The categories act as a tree, and in order to function properly they need one and only one root. Since you can have multiple root categories, these need one more level above. This is where the category with id 1 comes in. This is not visible anywhere and you cannot edit it, but it helps the category tree work properly. Take a look in the `catalog_category_entity` table and you will see a record with id 1.

Comment: @Marius thanks for your reply. If my understanding is correct this 1 will necet get changed right? Even If I add other a root category whose id will be 10 then this 10 will be under 1. So If i check and subcategory of new root category it will become 1/10/<Crrent Category ID> am I right?

Comment: @invissible you are right.

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
$level = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getLevel();
if($level > 1){                 
    echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName();
    }
    else{
    echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName());
    }
```

Simply copy and paste this code :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but you're 5 months late :)

Comment: Welcome to the Magento Stack. You are quite right to answer an old question if you have a good answer that hasn't already been covered.  Answers are for the good of the community and not just for the benefit of the OP.  Keep it up! :)

Comment: This answer will be wrong if you're on level 3 and deeper, as it returns first Parent, while question was about top one.

Comment: While this isn't a complete solution, one could loop until the desired level is reached. Pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You could use getParentCategories() on the current category and then call array_pop to get the last element. Do it twice to get the second last element.