# How to get all active categories and subcategories in product listing page?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, category

My categories and subcategories hierarchy to a product listing page :

- Products

  - Refrigerator

    - back-bar fridges

      - Product listing(here)

Now, what i'm trying to get is while i'm in product listing page i want to get all the parent categories and subcategories with respective links.

I got answer from [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4606/how-to-get-top-parent-category-from-current-category-object)
But, i failed to get all parent items (subcategories and subcategories)

```
$path = $category->getPath();          
What i get is : 0(root)/2(Magento root)/444(products)
```

And it escapes all the middle subcategories. In my case it escaped `Refrigerator/backbar fridges`

Comment: Are you looking for *only* all the parent and child categories of the given category where you product is listed?

Answer (score 0):

this will show like breadcrum.

I know this is quite old, but I'd like to share my solution anyway as it doesn't override/clone any core files.

```
In your custom module add the following to your config.xml:

<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_init>
                <observers>
                    <breadcrumb_categorypath_product_init>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class><Your Namespace>_<Your Module>_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>fullBreadcrumbCategoryPath</method>
                    </breadcrumb_categorypath_product_init>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_init>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Create an Observer.php in /app/code/local///Model/

Add the following to your Observer.php:

```
class <Your Namespace>_<Your Module>_Model_Observer {
    public function fullBreadcrumbCategoryPath(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $current_product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        if( $current_product ) {
            $categories = $current_product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->setPageSize(1);
            foreach( $categories as $category ) {
                Mage::unregister('current_category');
                Mage::register('current_category', $category);
            }
        }
    }
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get all active categories:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this give help you a bit.

```
<?php 

$parentCategoryId = 222;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

// Get 1 Level sub category of Parent category
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
              {
                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a><li>';

  }
}
*/
?>
```