# Specific category not recognizing subcategories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, products-view

I want to show a form in product view only for a specific category.

```
<?php if ($specificCatID == 3 ): ?>
form code
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is working but do not recognize the subcategories products. I need it to show the form on category *(3)* and all subcategories products view.

How to show the form also on subcategories products view?

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4606/how-to-get-top-parent-category-from-current-category-object

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about would be to have a custom module for that. A good tutorial on that can be found [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643).

Now for the module itself. We'll need a Block class for some business logic and a template file. But first let's create the `config.xml`.

Swap out `[namespace]` and `[module]` for some actual names. Be careful, they're case sensitive.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <[namespace]_[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Block</class>
            </[namespace]_[module]>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now for the block class, create a directory `Block` in your module folder with a file called `Form.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Form extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function canShowForm()
    {
        $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        /**
        * If no current_category is set which can be because the product
        * was accessed via search or direct URL retrieve all the categories from the product
        */
        $categoryIds = ($category) ? array($category->getId()) : $product->getCategoryIds();

        /**
         * Now we'll also get the IDs for the children
         */
        $filterArray = array();
        foreach ($categoryIds as $id) {
            $filterArray[] = array('attribute'=> 'path','like' => "%/{$id}/%");
        }
        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter($filterArray);

        /**
         * Now check if 3 belongs to parents or children
         */
        if (in_array(3, $children->getAllIds()) || in_array(3, $categoryIds) ) { // 3 is the allowed category
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see we have a method here that contains the business logic. It's always advised to move your business logic to a block class and not put it in the template file.

Now for adding it to the front end. In your template there should be a layout XML which you can edit. It's either a `local.xml`, `catalog.xml` or some template specific name. Find it and add the following.

```
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="content">
      <block type="[namespace]_[module]/form" name="[namespace]_[module].form" template="[namespace]_[module]/form.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This adds the form to the main content section of the product page. If you want to display it somewhere else modify accordingly but let's use this to test it.

Now create a directory `[namespace]_[module]` in the template folder and add a file `form.phtml`. In that file we'll use the `canShowForm` method to determine if this is a product we can show the form for.

```
<?php if ($this->canShowForm()):?>
   <!-- The HTML of the form goes here -->
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
<?php $currentCategory = $this->getCategory(); ?>
<?php $level = $currentCategory->getLevel(); ?>
<?php while($level > 0): ?>
    <?php $categoryIds = array($currentCategory->getId());
    <?php $currentCategory = $currentCategory->getParentCategory(); ?>
    <?php $level = is_object($currentCategory) ? $currentCategory->getLevel() : 0; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print_r($categoryIds); //Array with all categories IDs  ?>
```

Or use `explode` slash in `$this->getCategory()->getPath()`

Answer (score 0):

you can create one helper function to checkout whether product is belongs to category 3 or not with its subcategory

just pass product object in to function

```
 public function categoryisSpecific(($objProduct)) {

$categories = $objProduct->getCategoryIds();

    return in_array(3, explode('/',$categories  ));
}
```

hope this will work for you,